# Asynchronously Messaging in JMS

Tags: java, jms

I have a question about JMS. I read the related questions and answers but I could not find a clear answer.

**I have a basic producer like this:**

```java
public class AsyncProducer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
    Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/asyncQueue");

    try (
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        JMSContext jmsContext = cf.createContext();
        ){

        JMSProducer producer = jmsContext.createProducer();
        producer.send(queue, "Async Message");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

  }

}
```

**This is my MessageListener:**

```java
public class AsyncConsumerListener implements MessageListener {

   @Override
   public void onMessage(Message message) {
      try {
         TextMessage text = (TextMessage) message;
         System.out.println("Consumer: message received: " + text.getText());
      } catch (JMSException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

**And this is my consumer:**

```java
public class AsyncConsumer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
    Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/asyncQueue");

    try (
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        JMSContext jmsContext = cf.createContext();
        ){

        JMSConsumer consumer = jmsContext.createConsumer(queue);

        consumer.setMessageListener(new AsyncConsumerListener());

        //Thread.sleep(10000);  

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

  }

}
```

First I run the `Producer` class and send a message to the queue. Then, when I run the `Consumer` class.  If `Thread.sleep(10000);` line is commented out then the `Consumer` doesn't receive the message. But when I debug the `Consumer` it receives the message.

I know that when a message comes the listener is called in a separate thread. In this example there is a message in the queue, but the consumer doesn't receive the message unless `Thread.sleep(10000)` is run.

Why does my `Consumer` not receive the message when the `Thread.sleep(10000);` line is commented out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consumer won't receive the message without the `Thread.sleep(10000)` because the program will *exit* before the broker dispatches the message to it. This is the nature of *asynchronous* (i.e. non-blocking) message consumers. If you don't have something to keep your `main` method from exiting then it will simply reach the end and terminate.